# Scala contravariance and covariance

Tags: scala, types, covariance, contravariance

I am playing around with the typesystem of scala and found a strange case. I have a strong reason to believe, I don't understand covariant and covariance.

This is my problem case:

I have two classes, Point and ColorPoint, which is a subclass of Point.

```
class Point(val x : Int, val y : Int)
class ColorPoint(x : Int, y : Int, val red : Int, val green : Int, val blue : Int) extends Point(x,y)
```

This class casts B to A, while B should be a supertype of A:

```
class CoVariance[+A]{
 def cast[B >: A](x : B) : A = {
  return x.asInstanceOf[A] 
 }
}
```

This class casts B to A, while B should be a supertype of A:

```
class ContraVariance[-A]{
 def cast[B, A <: B](x : B) : A = {
    return x.asInstanceOf[A]
 }
}
```

Case 1:

```
val co = new CoVariance[Point]
val color_point = new ColorPoint(1,2,3,4,5)
val point_co = co.cast(color_point) 
println(point_co.x)
```

If I write this out:

```
// Covariance[Point] -> 
// cast[B :> Point](x : B) : Point -> (fill in ColorPoint)
// Cast[ColorPoint :> Point] : Point
```

I would expect this to be incorrect, because ColorPoint is not a supertype of Point, but scala doesn't complain.

Next one:

```
val contra = new ContraVariance[Point]
val color_point_contra = new ColorPoint(1,2,3,4,5)
val point_contra = contra.cast(color_point_contra) 
println(point_contra.x)
```

If I write this out:

```
// ContraVariance[Point] -> 
// cast[B, Point <: B](x : B) : Point -> (fill in ColorPoint)
// cast[ColorPoint, Point <: ColorPoint] : Point
```

I also expect this to be incorrect, but scala doesn't complain. I would say Point is not a subtype of ColorPoint.

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what covariant and contravariant positions are. It doesn't imply that you're able to *cast* between certain types, it just establishes the inheritance relationship between parameterized types.

You're only able to mark type parameters as in covariant or contravariant positions. When you say `Container[+A]`, you're saying that you can treat all instances of `Container[A]` as subtypes of `Container[B]` if `A` is a subtype of `B`. This makes sense for immutable container classes: You can think of a `List[Person]` to be a parent of `List[Employee]`. Note this says nothing about casting rules -- those go unchanged.

Contravariant is similar, but the opposite. If you have `Writer[-A]`, it says `Writer[A]` is a subtype of `Writer[B]` if `B` is a subtype of `A`. You can see how this makes intuitive sense too: If you have a `Writer[Person]` as something that can write a Person into some destination and you have `Writer[Employee]` as a writer that can only write Employees, it makes sense for `Writer[Employee]` to be a parent of `Writer[Person]` since writing a `Person` is a sub-task of writing a full `Employee`, even though it is the opposite for the types themselves.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now. It's very alike co and contra variant functors. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess they are, they are composable; for each morphism `f : A -> B` and `g : B -> C`, we have `Type(f) : Type[A] -> Type[B]` and `Type(g) : Type[B] -> Type[C]`, then `Type(f . g) = Type(f) . Type(g)` seems to hold.

Answer (score 2):

1. `asInstanceOf[T]` ignores typechecks. So you may even have the following cast:

   ```
   def cast[B](a:A):B = a.asInstanceOf[B]
   ```

   for any `A` and `B`.

   Thus in your case Scala won't complain.
2. If I understand correctly, you want to have `cast` method only when the types are in proper relations (parent-child). I think, you needn't have `+/-` in class declaration. Only two different casts:

   ```
   implicit class CastToParent[A](a:A) {
     def cast[B >: A]:B = a.asInstanceOf[B]
   }


   implicit class CastToChild[A](a:A) {
     def cast[B <: A]:B = a.asInstanceOf[B]
   }
   ```

   this allows you to have the desired conversions.

   ```
   trait A
   trait B extends A
   trait C
   val a:A = new B {}
   val b   = a.cast[B] //parent to child
   val a1  = b.cast[A] //child to parent.
   val c   = a.cast[C] // don't compile
   ```

Comment: @EdgarKlerks `asInstanceOf` is a lie. What it means is "compiler, forget what you know, and trust me on this".