# What is - used for, with a parameter to a Sealed Trait

Tags: scala

```
    sealed trait Condition[-CS <: AnyRef] {
  def toCondition: Condition[CS] = this
}
```

I know that, if it's only CS<: AnyRef, it means CS has to be a subset of the datatype any ref. But what is - used for? That it can be anything other than a subset of this data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - Covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935441/scala-covariance)

Comment: The minus sign (`-`) means that the trait `Condition` is contravariant on its type parameter. Contravariance is more than a little counterintuitive. Do a search for "scala contravariance". [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668353/scala-contravariance-and-covariance) is a good place to start.